# Rails how to reference a has_one in a collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

First of all, here's my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_one :event
    has_one :user_details, :dependent => :destroy
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_details, :event
end

class UserDetails < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    def full_name
        [self.first_name, self.last_name].compact.join(' ')
    end
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

And I have this line in one of my views

```
<%= collection_select(:event, :user_id, User.all, :id, :email) %>
```

It works just fine and displays all of the users emails in the dropdown list. But what i want to display is the users full_name in the dropdown list which is part of the user_details model.

How can i do that?

```
# basically i need to change :email to something like :user_details.full_name, but i'm not sure how.
<%= collection_select(:event, :user_id, User.all, :id, :email)  %>
```

**EDIT**

I have tried:

```
# undefined method `full_name' for :user_details:Symbol
<%= collection_select(:event, :user_id, User.all, :id, :user_details.full_name)  %>

# This shows the dropdown with a bunch of UserDetails objects aka #<UserDetails:asfjoisdfa>
<%= collection_select(:event, :user_id, User.all, :id, :user_details)  %>

# undefined method `full_name' for #<User:0x007ff18bf0c470>
<%= collection_select(:event, :user_id, User.all, :id, :full_name)  %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the following

```
<%= collection_select(:event, :user_id, User.all, :id, :full_name)  %>
```

but you have to declare the `full_name` method on the user model.

```
# user.rb
def full_name
  user_details.full_name
end
```

or you can use delegate

```
delegate :full_name, to: :user_details
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what delegate does?

Comment: perhaps it's better if you look at the official docs :) http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
<%= link_to "#{user.user_details.full_name}", "mailto:#{email}" %>
```

In your view, and let me know how you get on...

**EDIT**
Define a helper method, that returns user_details.full_name, in your user.rb file and use that:

`<%= collection_select(:event, :user_id, User.all, :id, :*method_returning_user_details.full_name* %>`

Comment: That doesn't work. You'd need something like `user.user_details.full_name`.

Comment: I can't just put that into the view because it's not going to know what the variable `user` is. I'm not in a loop or anything.

Comment: In my layout i'm already doing this `<%= current_user.user_details.full_name %>` so i know it works.

Comment: I'm creating a collection_select. Why would i put that in a loop?

Comment: My mistake... Clarify your question -- what do you expect to get? What are you getting? What have you tried?

Comment: "But what i want to display is the users full_name in the dropdown list which is part of the user_details model. "

Comment: There were 2 more questions, I'd like answers to on every SO question, and rarely do.

Answer (score -2):

Try : 
this in your view

**Update:**

```
 <% @fullname = User_details.fullname %>
```

and in your collection_select

```
  <%= collection_select(:event, :user_id, User.all, :id, @fullname) %>
```

and tell me what's the progress.

Comment: That gives this error: `undefined method `user_details' for #<Class:0x007ff18b968ca8>` because `User` hasn't been defined. I mean like we never called `User.find(0)`.